# Representing a document in 2-up format in word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

I've got a 'handover document' that I'd like to include in the appendix at the end of my Masters level thesis.  Due to the length of this document, and the unlikelihood of it being read in detail, I'd like to include this section of the appendix in A5 format.

Essentially I would like to have a landscape A4 sheet, with two A5 sheets in portrait.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There might be slight differences depending on the Word version you're using, but in general it's like this:

1. Navigate to the end of your thesis
2. Insert a **section break** (Page Layout > Breaks > Next page). This will split your document in two sections which you can format differently, new section starting on a new page
3. Change Orientation of this new section to Landscape (Page Layout > Orientation)
4. Insert a 2x1 table (Insert > Table) and make its borders invisible (Design > Borders > Line style No Border)

   - Alternatively, instead of a table you can set the layout to 2-column (Page Layout > Columns) depending on your needs
5. If you wish to add some usual pages after, just add another section break and format this section as portrait A4.